# Setting color using Html.fromHtml to TextView in Android is not working

Tags: android, html, textview

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I am trying to set different colors to text in a `TextView`. I mean multiple colors in a `TextView`. I am trying to use `Html.fromHtml` to do it. But it is not working.

`TextView` xml:

```
<TextView
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/general_line_spacing"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/general_line_spacing"
    android:textSize="@dimen/mm_item_title_size"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
    android:id="@+id/mm_item_tv_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This is how I set text to `TextView`

```
String title = post.getTitle();
if(title!=null && title.length()>MAX_TITLE_LENGTH)
{
    title = title.substring(0, MAX_TITLE_LENGTH);
    title = title + "<font color='color:#2bb1ff'> .... read more</font>";
}
viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(title));
```

As you can see, I am setting font color using html. But it is not working. "read more" text appended is always just the same color with other letters. So I tried this way too.

```
title = title + "<![CDATA[<font color='color:#2bb1ff'> .... read more</font>]]>";
```

It is not working. This also:

```
title = title + "<span style=color:'#2bb1ff'> .... read more</span>";
```

So how can I set multiple colors to text in a `TextView`?

Comment: Have you tried escaping characters when using quotation marks for the HTML colour code? Similar to: <font color=\"#47a842\">

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
title = title + "<font color=#2bb1ff> .... read more</font>";
```

Comment: is it possible to pass color from color.xml ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use it like that:

```js
title = title + "<span style='color: #2bb1ff;'> .... read more</span>";
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use Spannable like this :

```
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    SpannableString str1 = new SpannableString(titleText);
    builder.append(str1);
    SpannableString str2 = new SpannableString("....read more");
    str2.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorGrey)), 0, str2.length(), 0);
    builder.append(str2);
    viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(builder);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hope this will help you:
title = title + "![CDATA[<font color=#2bb1ff> .... read more</font>]]"
```

Note: Please don't use static text in code. try to use it on string.xml file then get it from there.
 Example:

```
<string name="read_more"><![CDATA[<font color=#2bb1ff> .... read more</font>]]></string>
title = title + activity.getResources().getString(R.string.read_more);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've checked in my application that's code working.

```
title = title + "<font color='#000'> .... read more</font>";
txt_view.setText(Html.fromHtml(title));
```

Please check carefully in your code may be your title is null.

Comment: `fromHtml(String)` is deprecated

Comment: Use fromHtml(String source, int flags) now